# How can I get rid of common areas in this plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to realize the domains in which $\sin x<0$  and $\sin x \geq 0$. I use this code

```
Plot[{Sin[x], If[Sin[x] < 0, 0], If[Sin[x] >= 0, 0]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, 
   Directive[Yellow, Opacity[60], Thickness[.08]], 
   Directive[Red, Opacity[1], Thickness[.03]]}]
```

and I get
[image]

In the plot, the yellow and red parts have some common areas which are not true! How can I modify it to have the exact result?  I have to use a big thickness for them since I want them to be visible over a large number of $x$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `CapForm["Butt"]` inside `Directive`:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], If[Sin[x] < 0, 0], If[Sin[x] >= 0, 0]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, 
   Directive[Yellow, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.08]], 
   Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.03]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your time and answers.

Comment: @charmin, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.